# Hero animation not working in List when setting row's id dynamically

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-animation

Recently ran into an issue trying to perform Hero animation using `matchedGeometryEffect` in SwiftUI. My issue is that setting `id` for `matchedGeometryEffect` effect dynamically isn't working as expected.

This is what I have so far:

```
import SwiftUI

struct HeroAnimationTest: View {
    let items: [Item] = [.init(id: 1), .init(id: 2), .init(id: 3), .init(id: 4)]

    @State var selectedItemInRowIndex: Int? = nil
    @Namespace var namespace

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(items, id: \.id) { item in
                ItemListRow(namespace: namespace, item: item) { tappedItem in
                    withAnimation {
                        selectedItemInRowIndex = tappedItem.id
                    }
                }
            }
            .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
            .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
            .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(h: 16, v: 8))
        }
        .animation(.spring(), value: selectedItemInRowIndex)
        .scrollIndicators(.never)
        .listStyle(.plain)
        .overlay {
            if selectedItemInRowIndex != nil {
                largeGreen
            }
        }
    }

    var largeGreen: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.black
                .onTapGesture {
                    withAnimation {
                        selectedItemInRowIndex = nil
                    }
                }
            Color.green
                .frame(width: 200, height: 400)
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: selectedItemInRowIndex, in: namespace)
            Text("ID -> \(selectedItemInRowIndex ?? 0)")
        }
    }
}

struct HeroAnimationTest_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HeroAnimationTest()
    }
}

struct Item {
    let id: Int
}

struct ItemListRow: View {
    @State var enlargeElement = false
    let namespace: Namespace.ID

    let item: Item
    let onGreenTap: (Item) -> Void

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("ID -> \(item.id)")
            VStack {
                Color.green
            }
            .frame(width: 100, height: 40)
            .matchedGeometryEffect(id: item.id, in: namespace)
            .onTapGesture {
                onGreenTap(item)
            }
            VStack {
                Color.yellow
            }
            .frame(width: 100, height: 40)
        }
    }
}
```

Current result:

[image]

I tried to hard-code `id` for `largeGreen` inside `.matchedGeometryEffect(id: 3, in: namespace)` to check if animation would work, and it does:

[image]

Animation with hard-coded `id` is the expected result, but obviously it's only working for the 3rd row. Is it even possible to achieve this effect for a green container in every row?

I'd really appreciate if anyone could take a look and give me some hint of what I'm missing here. I've been looking at this for a few hours now, but still can't figure out what went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I finally figured it out. It turns out that in order for `matchedGeometryEffect` to work, its `id` needs to be unwrapped, assigning optional just won't work.

So, what I did was:

1. Extracted `largeGreen` to a `ExpandedLargeGreen` with `selectedItemIdx` &
   `show` parameters with `@Binding` property wrapper, and `namespace`.
2. And then inside `.overlay` closure within `HeroAnimationTest` unwrapped
   optional Binding `selectedItemInRowIndex`. In case it's not nil and
   `show` is set to true  `ExpandedLargeGreen` will be displayed with
   proper animation.
3. Also set animation value to `show` instead of `selectedItemInRowIndex`.

Full code:

```
struct HeroAnimationTest: View {
    let items: [Item] = [.init(id: 1), .init(id: 2), .init(id: 3), .init(id: 4)]

    @State var selectedItemInRowIndex: Int? = nil
    @State var show = false
    @Namespace var namespace

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            List {
                ForEach(items, id: \.id) { item in
                    ItemListRow(namespace: namespace, item: item) { tappedItem in
                        withAnimation {
                            selectedItemInRowIndex = tappedItem.id
                            show.toggle()
                        }
                    }
                }
                .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
                .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
                .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(h: 16, v: 8))
            }
            .animation(.spring(), value: show)
            .scrollIndicators(.never)
        .listStyle(.plain)
        }
        .overlay {
            if let selectedIdx = Binding($selectedItemInRowIndex), show {
                ExpandedLargeGreen(selectedItemIdx: selectedIdx, show: $show, namespace: namespace)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ExpandedLargeGreen: View {
    @Binding var selectedItemIdx: Int
    @Binding var show: Bool
    var namespace: Namespace.ID

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.black
                .onTapGesture {
                    withAnimation {
                        show.toggle()
                    }
                }
            Color.green
                .frame(width: 200, height: 400)
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: selectedItemIdx, in: namespace)
            Text("ID -> \(selectedItemIdx)")
        }
    }
}

struct HeroAnimationTest_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HeroAnimationTest()
    }
}

struct Item {
    let id: Int
}

struct ItemListRow: View {
    @State var enlargeElement = false
    let namespace: Namespace.ID

    let item: Item
    let onGreenTap: (Item) -> Void

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("ID -> \(item.id)")
            VStack {
                Color.green
            }
            .frame(width: 100, height: 40)
            .matchedGeometryEffect(id: item.id, in: namespace)
            .onTapGesture {
                onGreenTap(item)
            }
            VStack {
                Color.yellow
            }
            .frame(width: 100, height: 40)
        }
    }
}
```

Final result:

[image]